# Unable to get simple tree working in AngularJS + AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-tree

All of required libraries are available. But I receive error :

```
angular.js:11855 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in list, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=item%20in%20list&p1=string%3A%22&p2=%22
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:263)
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:24831)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (angular.js:14373)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14508)
```

I could fix this by adding track by $index to ng-repeat but this is not same as sample code given on homepage : https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree

index.html :

```
<!doctype html>

<html ng-app="app">

<head>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-tree.js"></script>
<script src="tree.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/angular-ui-tree.min.css" />

</head>

</head>


<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


        <div>

            <div ui-tree>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list  track by $index" ui-tree-node>
      <div ui-tree-handle>
        {{item.title}}
      </div>
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.items">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.items  track by $index" ui-tree-node>
          <div ui-tree-handle>
            {{subItem.title}}
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
</div>

</body>

<div ui-tree>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list" ui-tree-node>
      <div ui-tree-handle>
        {{item.title}}
      </div>
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="item.items">
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.items" ui-tree-node>
          <div ui-tree-handle>
            {{subItem.title}}
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
</html>
tree.js : 

var app = angular.module('app' , ['ui.tree']);

app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.list = "[{ \"id\": \"1\", \"title\": \"1. dragon-breath\", \"items\": [] }]"

                });
```

Update :

By "not working" I mean nothing is being display on screen, just error returned to console.

Comment: whats not working here ?.,could you please elaborate more on not working Is the ui-tree not loading on DOM?..

Comment: @shushanthp please see update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two problems $scope.list is a string , use as below

```
 $scope.lists = [{ "id": "1", "title": "1. dragon-breath", "items": [] }];
```

As far ui-tree is concerned , uses `$$hashkey` not `$index` ,So it will be

```
ng-repeat="list in lists track by list.$$hashKey"
```

or

```
ng-repeat="list in lists track by $id(list)"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could fix this by adding track by $index to ng-repeat but this is not same as sample code given on homepage

Your sample data (see `$scope.list`) is also not the same as the one in the example provided on github project page. That's why you had to add `track by` so as to get rid of the error.

***Why you get the error:***

You get the error because you declared `$scope.list` as a string:

```
$scope.list = "[{ \"id\": \"1\", \"title\": \"1. dragon-breath\", \"items\": [] }]"
```

This is a collection of characters, and it has duplicates in it. For example there are multiple `{` or `i` in `$scope.list`.

It should be more like:

```
$scope.list = [{ 
    "id": "1", 
    "title": "1. dragon-breath", 
    "items": [] 
}];
```

Comment: What data are you referring to ?  I used data referred to at http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example